# Word for (feeling) a really strong visceral impulse that draws you to something

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for when a person feels very drawn to something in a way that the object itself is calling out to you and as a result, you feel drawn to it. 
I'm trying to write an essay on the first chapter of Helen Keller's Story of my Life, and in one account, she recounts looking at the shadows of leaves on the wall of her bathroom when she was only a year old and getting so excited by looking at them that she walked towards them. I need to describe how she was drawn to nature...but I can't find the word.

Comment: **beckoned** and **invited** come to mind, but sadly don't really work here.

Comment: Isn't this known as "love"?

Answer (score 2):

When one has that feeling, it can be said that the *something* has an ***allure***.

In the example scenario, Helen could not resist the ***allure*** of *the shadows of leaves on the wall of her bathroom*.

ODO:

> **[allure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/allure)**
>   *NOUN* [mass noun]
>   The quality of being powerfully and mysteriously attractive or fascinating.
>
> ‘One man who knows, all too well, Everest's seductive allure is
>   British climber Doug Scott.’

Answer (score 1):

According to your description `a word for when a person feels very drawn to something in a way that the object itself is calling out to you and as a result, you feel drawn to it.`

I'd suggest the word **gravitate.** On-line [Thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/gravitate) has following synonyms: be pulled, be influenced, sink, be attracted, drift etc.

Cambridge On-line dictionary define it as: 
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gravitate

> to be attracted to or move toward something:
>
> > "People tend to *gravitate* to the beaches here."
> >
> > "Capybaras are so magical other animals gravitate towards them."

Comment: Please don't use code blocks when you aren't writing code.